# sym not working with vector has more than 1 element

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, sym

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,1), B = c(2,2,3))
variables <- c("A", "B") 
dplyr::count(df, !!!rlang::sym(variables))
```

```r
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

It works if `variables` is either `A` or `B`, but not both.

Answer (score 3):

For this `syms` is needed.  According to `?sym`

> sym() creates a symbol from **a string** and syms() creates a list of symbols from **a character vector**.

```
dplyr::count(df, !!!rlang::syms(variables))
  A B n
1 1 2 2
2 1 3 1
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't able to see that there was an `s`

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. The problem with the OPs method is that `sym()` will return a single symbol, but we need a list of symbols. Use the excellent answer by akrun, with the vectorized `syms` or `purrr::map(sym)`.

Or, without rlang, double/tripple bangs etc, we can do it within dplyr with `across(all_of())`

```
Library(tidyverse)

count(df, !!!syms(variables)) #As suggested by @akrun

count(df, across(all_of(variables)))

count(df, !!!map(variables, sym))

  A B n
1 1 2 2
2 1 3 1
```